# How to defend against 6pool?

Tags: starcraft-2

I am specifically interested in countering 6pool early rush as Protoss but you can include other races too.

Comment: Isn't your question rather how to defend *against* 6pool? It sounds like you're asking how to defend *your* 6pool. Or did you mean 'defeat'?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you want to do is something along these lines:
[image]

You use your first Gateway and Cybernetics core (or second Gatway, or Pylon) to create a wall with a single hole, and you chronoboost out your first Zealot to hold that hole.

In the case of a 6 Pool you should be able to get that first Zealot out just around the time the first 6 Zerglings arrive. Many times this means you won't have the Zealot in time to stop the Zerglings.  I highly recommend using the Zealot to block the hole (still) and using your probes to defending against the Zerglings.  You should have sufficient Probes (a dozen or so) to hold off lings, but if you chase the Zerglings with the Zealot, his follow up pushes are going to get into your base.

Usually you will use a second Zealot to chase down any remaining lings who have survived to that point.

Normally I don't recommend using a Pylon as part of your Wall because pylons have low health and are susceptible to Baneling busts or pressure later on; I much perfer the wall-in shown in this picture.   However, if you scout 6 pool it may not always be feasible to rely on getting that Cybernetics Core down and you maybe forced to use a Pylon or Second Gateway.

Remember, buildings, while they are being built, still act as a wall.

Comment: Perhaps you should just assume a 6-pool and use the scouting probe to get a small advantage in resources?

Comment: @Ivo I consider the value of scouting much larger than any other value that probe could bring

Comment: Intel from good scouting is indeed priceless. But I do think it's worth considering always walling in against Zerg, due to the possibility of early pools.

Comment: If you end up scouting a 6-pool and lost the 50 minerals you needed to get 2 zealots earlier, than what did all that scouting win you?

Comment: @Ivo the knowledge that you needed to get 2 Zealots earlier.  Without that knowledge you may not have gotten that first Zealot fast enough or you may have gotten 2-3 Zealots only to learn he is Roach Rushing and you won't have time to get more than 1 Stalker.  Knowledge isn't priceless its directly proportional to how much it might have influenced you.  In this example 100-500 minerals and probably the game.  This number is usually considered greater than 50

Comment: @Wik I've discussed the [cost](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10847/is-it-ok-to-build-a-wall-not-on-mains-but-on-naturals-choke/10908#10908) of walling in before, suffice to say it is a non-Zero number.  Worth considering? Definitely, I agree with you there.  Worth doing? That's a much longer discussion.

Comment: This depends on rush distance a fair bit. On a small map, you might not be able to get the cybernetics core up in time. Either way, probes can hold off the lings until the wall is up and the zealot(s) are out. Just don't chase the lings with probes, attack with 4-7 until the lings run and continue mining.

Answer (score 1):

"but you can include other races too."

Playing as Z, I really love the 11pool18hatch build.
Make sure to scout early to see what's coming.

If you see a super early pool, pump some lings to defend and counter attack. You should have plenty of time to build up defenses when scouting a 6pool.

I usually scout with my 9th.

If he goes for stand 13-15 pool, you have your queen earlier and can pump 7 drones with the first inject - should be almost as good as the other eco-openings.

cheers.

PS: Don't know too much about P tho :D

Answer (score 1):

Supplement to tzenes' answer.

If you scout a 6 pool (you should always scout), prefer to get a 2nd gateway instead of a cyber core. A 2 gate zealot push will easily win the game if the Zerg's 6 pool failed to do any serious damage.

Also, as Protoss, always wall off against Zerg; ideally with a wall similar to the picture tzenes has.

Finally, while a 6 pool can be done effectively on almost any map, it is worth considering that a 6 poll is really only common on the map "Steps of War".